# react-router-dom - how to use query params as path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently got an issue with URL including query params hitting the 404 error page. I need the query params due to this URL is a redirect from a 3rd Party application.

My router switch:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
            <Router>
                <ReactNotification />

                <React.StrictMode>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

                        {singleRouting.map((route, i) => (
                            <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
                        ))}
    
                        <Route path="*">
                            <Error />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </React.StrictMode>
            </Router>
        </React.Suspense>
    );
}

const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => {
    return (
        <Route
            exact={route.exact || undefined}
            path={route.path}
            render={(props) => (
                // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
                <route.component {...props} />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

My routes:

```
import FinanceBody from '../main/finance/FinanceBody';

const singleRouting = [{
    path: "/finance?:applicationId&:status&:supplierOrderReference",
    exact: true,
    component: FinanceBody 
}];

export { singleRouting };
```

Answer (score -1):

After continuous trail and error, I found that the answer was very basic.

Previous path:

```
path: "/finance?:applicationId&:status&:supplierOrderReference"
```

Updated path:

```
path: "/finance"
```

You can access the query params as normal within `location.search`